# How to get qemu binaries for mips

Tags: qemu

I am a new user for qemu. I successfully compiled for my system (x64) but when I tried to compile it for mips it generate error that Why I think that is there any way to get already compiled binary files.
Is there any way(sites) to get binaries for qemu for mips 32 or 64 or Can I generate binaries for mips from my x64 system?

Comment: http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/QEMU "A guide for installing Debian can be found here http://www.aurel32.net/info/debian_mips_qemu.php Is that what you want?